# Connect to CEN/XFS device from C#

Tags: c#, cen-xfs

I'm trying to connect my `C#` application to Encrypted PIN Pad through `CEN/XFS`.

I installed and read protocol documentation from [CEN website](https://www.cen.eu/work/areas/ICT/eBusiness/Pages/CWA15748.aspx). During my research I read that I should use `msxfs.dll` to connect to `XFS Manager` which is build in C language (at least that what I read), and there is no documentaion regarding this dll as Microsoft don't own it, and it follow CEN standards.

I'm lost and looking for some guidance regarding my starting point:

- Should I copy `msxfs.dll` beside my application and start calling `msxfs.dll` functions depending on CEN specicifations.
- Or I'm moving in the wrong path, and there is another way to build integration?

If anyone has any article or tutorial regarding how to connect to `CEN/XFS` using `C#` that will be very helpful, all the samples I found was through using `j/xfs` or they were describing how to build SPI functions not how to consume API functions.

Comment: _msxfs.dll_ is documented in _Application Programming Interface (API) - Service Provider Interface (SPI) - Programmer's Reference_. In that document you have the dll interfaz (methods, structs, etc, like: `WFSStartUp`, `WFSOpen`, `WFSGetInfo`, etc.). 
You can use the dll the same as any other dll from c#.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will try it

Comment: WFS Functions are the interface you use to cominicate with XFS from application. WFP are the functions that an SPI must to implement in order to be called from XFS manager when an application execute some WFS functions. WFM are functions you can use too, to allocate memory to be send to XFS. All are explained in the API document.